# Why are these two parameters in the jQuery source for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery source is wrapped in a closure, like this:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
   //awesome jQuery library code in here
})(window);
```

I don't understand why either of these parameters are needed.

Since `window` is a global variable, why does it need to be passed in? What's the purpose of passing in a global parameter and accessing it inside the closure with the same name?

What's the `undefined` parameter for? Why isn't any value passed to it?

Comment: window will be used a as local in this scope, making it faster to access, i think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has been answered already, but:

- passing in `window` a) allows code compression to munge the name (i.e. replacing it with a single-letter variable name within the anonymous function) and b) ensures that the variable references the window object at the time the library is defined, just in case anyone redefines `window` in the global scope after jQuery is loaded.
- including `undefined` as an argument (but not passing in a value) does the same thing for `undefined`, allowing variable munging and avoiding problems if the `undefined` variable is redefined (yup, Javascript allows this).

I believe in both cases this is supposed to speed up references to the variable, as it makes both global variables available in the function scope, which the interpreter will search before looking in the global scope. But I can't honestly imagine that the performance difference here is substantial - I think the biggest issue is the variable name munging, which makes for more compact code when minified.

Comment: If `window` was redefined in the global scope, wouldn't it still be redifined when you pass it in?

Comment: @PeterOlson - not if it's redefined later - this fixes the `window` reference at the time the jQuery library is loaded, so subsequent `window` shenanigans won't have any effect. I suppose if you redefine window before the library loads, this will break, but then you deserve what you get :).

Comment: @PeterOlson i guess then "code compression to munge" will be the reason

Comment: Come to think of it, the `undefined` variable can also be redefined, so this protects against that too. Updated the answer.