# var undefined = void 0; vs jquery's closure vs ...?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, undefined, void

Reading underscore's source, I noticed the use of `void 0` instead of `undefined`. I know in some browsers undefined can be overwritten, and that a solution to this, in many cases, is just omitting an argument when calling a function, or `return;`-ing. In fact, for minification purposes, it makes much more sense to do this rather than using `void 0`.

Also, [jquery's aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922963/why-are-these-two-parameters-in-the-jquery-source-for) to this issue:

```
(function (window, undefined){
  /* ... */
}(window));
```

seems to be better in every sense. It is much more readable than `void 0`, can be minified further, and might give some tiny performance boost as explained in the linked answer.

OK, void 0 appears about 6 times in underscore and 9 in backbone, so it doesn't make much of a difference. So, my question is: **Is there any reason or corner cases where `void 0` is preferable?**

Comment: I think it might have something to do with AMD and the loading of the scripts, which I don't really know much about. Also, an alternative, to improve readibility would be to just do [`var undefined = void 0;`](https://github.com/brainling/combobuilder/blob/7c7de6e9c58004425f2f775b96799ec8ba9fff2d/app/assets/javascripts/harmony.js#L9) at the top. Any reason not to do this?

Comment: According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), you shouldn't redefine `undefined`. The MDN also says that writing `void 0` or `void(0)` is equivalent to writing directly `undefined`.

Comment: i think "void 0" i just more straightforward than checking typeof for 'undefined'. it may also eliminate the need of using typeof to ensure you're not checking a variable named "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of why the "undefined argument" thing can be a horrible idea.

Let's say you get used to doing it. And you start applying it to other functions too, like this:

```
function doSomething(undefined) {
    // blah blah blah
    if( something == undefined) {
        // problem
    }
}
```

All good, right?

Let's say that this function is an event handler.

```
someElement.onclick = doSomething;
```

Oh dear. `doSomething` gets passed an Event object, which is most certainly *not* `undefined`!

`void 0` is much more robust, as it doesn't rely on a quirk or an assumption to work.

Comment: wouldn't you'd check typeof something == 'undefined' to avoid such ambiguity?

Comment: @SonicSoul I would, yes. I personally use `typeof x == 'undefined'` because it's the most readable.

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer because it gives a possible explanation to why some people might prefer `void 0`, not because I think using `void 0` is better.

Comment: In fact I think, as a general guideline I would say: Use plain old `undefined` if you have "total control" of your globals and know it isn't overwriten. To prevent redefinition either use jquery's method a single time, in a self executing anonymous function (more readable), or use `void 'anything could go but please use 0'` as a general more robust way of saying `undefined`, at the expense of maybe puzzling would be readers.

Comment: I think things like Closure Compiler and other minifiers reduce `typeof` and `== undefined` checks to compare against `void 0`, actually... Saves some bytes. A'course, you can save a few more by doing something like `_=void 0` at the start and using `_` to mean `undefined` thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `void 0` means `undefined`. Since older browsers `undefined` can be overwritten.
`void 0` is guaranteed and will always be undefined. But i do not think, there is no much difference between no argument undefined(jquery way) and `void 0`.

I think, `void 0` is just a coding preference.